# Inequality for PSD block matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite, hessian-matrix

Given a positive definite matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{(2n)\times(2n)}$ of the following block form

$$M = \begin{bmatrix}A & X\\X^\top& B\end{bmatrix},$$

where $A, B\in\mathbb{R}^n$ are positive definite.

**My question is**: is it possible to find the relation between $XX^\top$ or $X^\top X$ and $A, B$.
Something like $XX^\top+X^\top X\leq A^2+B^2$.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: From Sylvester's criterion $X^\top A^{-1} X < B$, but it's not probably what you want

Comment: Using Schur complements, we have $B>X^TA^{-1}X\ge\frac{1}{\|A\|}X^TX$ and $A>XB^{-1}X^T\ge\frac{1}{\|B\|}XX^T$. Thus $X^TX<\|A\|B$ and $XX^T<\|B\|A$. If you add them together, you also get $XX^T+X^TX\le\|B\|A+\|A\|B$.